# Rasters to PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster

I have been able to load rasters into my PostGIS database using the raster2pgsql tool and running it via the OSGeo4W shell. Files load where I want them to but appear in the database as one line files rather than sets of rows containing the pixel values that I want to be able to access. This a DTM raster and does appear to be of a format that is acceptable to PostGIS

```
raster2pgsql -s 27700 -C D://TEST_RUBBISH/terrain-5-dtm_3568783/nz/NZ25NE.asc staging.nz25ne|psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5433 -d Init_Study_Areas_from10
```

Additionally, these rasters will not display in QGIS whether I drag them in directly or via the PostGIS database

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend you add the -I command which will allow you to load the rasters into QGIS faster. this is a command I've used very succesfully to load a 90GB DEM into postgres and display it in QGIS. also the -t flag will help

`raster2pgsql.exe -s 2263 -d -C -I -M -l 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,20,26,32,64,132 B:\dem.tif -F -t 100x100 dem | psql -d thedb -U me -p 5432 -h host`

this is also a decent resource I found for beginers in PostGIS Rasters

https://github.com/lcalisto/workshop-postgis-raster

Comment: thanks for this. great to get a resource recommended by someone who has been through the pain

Comment: PostGIS Raster is like the wild west -- scant docs and examples on the internet but once you get the basics down its super smooth especially querying between raster and vector datasets

Answer (score 3):

That is how rasters are stored in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

You will have a line with an id, and a raster field. Usually *rid* and *rast*. If you tile the rasters (speeds up queries considerably) with *-t 128x128*  for example, you would have one line per tile.

You can add them to QGIS, using the DB manager. You right click on the layer in the DB manager and choose "Add to Canvas".

If you want to find out the raster value you can query the raster field:

[PostGIS raster geoTiff simple Lat/Lon query example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183418/postgis-raster-geotiff-simple-lat-lon-query-example)

```
SELECT ST_Value(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0,51.5),4326)) AS val
FROM my_raster
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0,51.5),4326));
```

Comment: Thankyou .. this has worked and enabled me to get DTM values at the intersection with a point feature I have in the same geographic space. I am finding DB Manager a bit clunky but will persevere. I had hoped it would be rather more interactive in displaying the results of queries run in DB manager directly.rather than having to 'load as new layer' . Can you recommend any other visualisation tool that works well with Postgres/PostGIS? Thanks

Comment: Even QGIS is extremely unstable when using PostGIS rasters. I find them useful because all of our data is in PostGIS to do queries. But we visualize our rasters from the raw files on the file system.